# Защитить внешнюю ссылку от перехода сторонние лица

Tags: c#, vue.js

Всем привет.
У меня есть проект на MVC (С#)
И Вебка с отчетами на Vue

Мне нужно из MVC по кнопочке переходить в веб морду с отчетами.
Ну перейти не сложно. Вставил гиперссылку не вебку и все.
А для работы самой вебки сделал WEB API

Но вопрос в следующем:
В проекте с MVC есть авторизация по логину и IP, которые я получаю из HttpContext.
Как защитить переход на ссылку Веб морды, чтобы туда не могли пройти не авторизованные пользователи ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача похожа на типичный RBAC сценарий (читать [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9)). В ASP.NET MVC есть встроенные средства как для поддержки авторизации пользователей и их ролей (для разграничения прав доступа), так и более простые механизмы для проверки авторизован пользователь или нет.

Рекомендую вглянуть на встроенный атрибут `[Authorize]` и его вариацию `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]` ([источник](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/simple?view=aspnetcore-7.0)). Если вы используете встроенные средства аутентификации на основе куки то вам, скорее всего хватит `[Authorize]`. Если у вас собственная система авторизации, и не полагается на Asp.Net авторизацию, то вам надо будет реализовать свой слой для проверки авторизации доступа `AuthorizationMiddleware`, читать [тут](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/customizingauthorizationmiddlewareresponse?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: Спасибо. Очень полезная информация. У меня своя реализация авторизации по IP и Логину..

Comment: @ankl тот факт, что вы не пользуетесь asp.net identity, не должен вам мешать использовать куки авторизацияю, если конечно она вам подходит. Посмотрите статью https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: @ankl чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить зелёную галочку слева от него